# JSON from file not loading into NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

In order to test the `JSON` handling of my app I have created a test.json file that I want to load into an `UITableView` in my `UIViewController` class. I have created the `JSON` file and made a separate json loading class (`JSONLoader`) that implements the code:

```
 #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

 @interface JSONLoader : NSObject

 //return an array of chat objects from the json file given by url
 - (NSArray *)chattersFromJSONFile:(NSURL *)url;

 @end
```

in the **.h** file, in the **.m** file I have:

```
 #import "JSONLoader.h"
 #import "Chatter.h"

 @implementation JSONLoader

 - (NSArray *)chattersFromJSONFile:(NSURL *)url {
 //create a NSURLRequest with the given URL
 NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                          cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
                                      timeoutInterval:30.0];
  //get data
  NSURLResponse *response;
  NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request  returningResponse:&response error:nil];

  //create NSDictionary from the JSON data
  NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

  //create new array to hold chatter information
  NSMutableArray *localChatters = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

  //get an Array of dictionaries with the key "chatters"
  NSArray *chatterArray = [jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"chatters"];

  //iterate through array of dictionaries
  for(NSDictionary *dict in chatterArray) {
    //create new chatter object for each one and initialize it with info from the  dictionary
    Chatter *chatter = [[Chatter alloc] initWithJSONDictionary:dict];
    //add the chatter to an array
    [localChatters addObject:chatter];
    }
    //return array
    return localChatters;
    }

    @end
```

Which I believe will work for both a `JSON` file loaded from a `URL` (the end goal) and also a `JSON` file I have in my *Xcode* project as a test. In the `-viewDidLoad` of my **viewController.m** file I use:

```
     //create a new JSONLoader with a local file from URL
     JSONLoader *jsonLoader = [[JSONLoader alloc] init];
     NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"test" withExtension:@"json"];
      NSLog(@"%@",url);

     //load the data on a background queue
     //use for when connecting a real URL
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
                                                                    _localChatters =     [jsonLoader chattersFromJSONFile:url];
                                                                     NSLog(@"%@",_localChatters);
                                                                    //push data on main thread (reload table view once JSON has arrived)
                                                                    [self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
                                                                    });
```

I import the `JSONLoader` file and also the class the represents a test `JSON` object (singular chatter) and in my implementation I declare a `NSArray *_localChatters`.

I'm pretty convinced this should work, however when I `NSLog(...)` the array it displays empty `()`, where it should have a list of class objects. This means the `JSON` is never being parsed by my `JSONLoader` in the first place.

Any particular reason this could happen?

Comment: Don't complain until you fix this bug: `error:nil`.

Comment: Thanks, I added error checking and I got it returns "the operation couldn't be completed". (Cocoa error 3840). I did some research [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11594617/ios-json-deserialization-failure-stig-nsjsonserializer/11596858#11596858) however I still can't get my head around how I should fix this particular example. It can't recognize my test.json file?

Comment: Which error are you checking, the one from NSURLConnection or the one from NSJSONSerialization?  And have you printed out the JSON?  (Convert NSData to NSString using UTF8 char set, then log the string.)

Comment: Note that you did not quote the **entire** error message.  What is the rest of it??

Comment: I added a NSError *error  = nil; then for both of them I added &error and did a NSLog localizedDescription, it checks both. however I think from the error it is the NSURLConnection. As of right now the JSON is hardcoded into a test.json file that I wanted to access from the mainBundle, URLforResource: name withExtension: json, I've printed out the path, it seems to be correct so the code recognizes the file is there.

Comment: also thats the only error that shows from the NSLog, "The operation couldn't be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)"

Comment: No, there is more to the message, if you NSLog it.  Look at the question you linked above -- he got `2012-07-21 23:59:31.376 Whisper.Client.IOS[1058:fe03] Error : Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (No string key for value in object around character 1.) UserInfo=0xc9632e0 {NSDebugDescription=No string key for value in object around character 1.}`

Comment: (Don't log `localizedDescription`, just log the whole NSError object.)

Comment: I see what you mean, here it is: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Badly formed object around character 492.) UserInfo=0xdc0d810 {NSDebugDescription=Badly formed object around character 492.}

Comment: So you need to log the JSON string (as I described above) and figure out about where character 492 is.

Comment: It was a comma that should have been there, thanks for everything @HotLicks, works great now.

Comment: Don't forget that if you Google for "json parser" there are several online sites where you can paste a JSON string and have it syntax-checked and see it nicely formatted.

Comment: Paste your JSON string into [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com)