# Read data from geoJson file in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, geojson

I'm trying to read data from geojson file using this code:

```
NSString *jsonPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"roads_json" ofType:@"geojson"];

NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[[NSData alloc]
                                                              initWithContentsOfFile:jsonPath]
                                                     options:0
                                                       error:nil];
NSLog(@"points:%@",json);
```

and the output:

points:(null)

any idea plz...

Comment: Could you post the contents of the geoJSON file?

Comment: Are you sure the file contains proper json format...Are you getting any error in console...

Comment: @vizllx yes ,the contains proper json format and no error in console...

Comment: You are not passing an error object, how will you know whether ther is any error?

Comment: Is the jsonPath being set correctly, have you tried logging it?

Comment: @ashish kakkad  this is json file link:http://txt.do/u7ht or http://textuploader.com/u7ht!

Comment: @ZeMoon this is JsonPath: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/7F2EE969-8750-4A0D-8BBB-FCD1FFF94F36/firstMapBox.app/roads_json.geojson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always best to pass an `NSError` object when using `NSJSONSerialization`. This way you can know what exactly is wrong.

```
NSError *error;
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[[NSData alloc]
                                                              initWithContentsOfFile:jsonPath]
                                                     options:0
                                                       error:&error];

if (error)
{
    NSLog(@"Could not serialize GeoJSON file: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
else
{
    //GeoJSON has been successfully decoded
}
```

Comment: Could not serialize GeoJSON file: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.) now this error show..

Comment: It basically means that the JSON file is not proper.

Comment: how i set the json file , jsonlint.com :Valid JSON

Comment: That's great. Could you post the contents of the GeoJSON file?

Comment: At least a part of the content will do.

Comment: Have you tried searching for the error yourself? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11174130/ios-5-json-parsing-results-in-cocoa-error-3840