# SwiftyJSON reading file - null

Tags: ios, json, swift, swifty-json

I am trying to read a j.json file in my project folder. I get no errors when executing the code, but instead of print out, all I get is "null". The initial file extention was .rtf.

```
let jsonFilePath:NSString = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("j", ofType: "json")!
let jsonData:NSData = NSData(contentsOfFile: jsonFilePath as String, options: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: nil)!
let json = JSON(data: jsonData)
println(json)
```

**Update:**

The problem was that I used rtf file (just as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11174130/ios-5-json-parsing-results-in-cocoa-error-3840)). Here`s correct code.

```
let jsonFilePath:NSString = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("<INPUT FILE NAME>", ofType: "<FILE EXTENTION>")!
let jsonData:NSData = NSData(contentsOfFile: jsonFilePath as String, options: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: nil)!
var error:NSError?
let json = JSON(data: jsonData, options: .AllowFragments, error: &error)
if error != nil{
   println(error!.localizedDescription)
   }
   else{
       println(json)
       }
```

Comment: did you checked the content of `j.json` file is a valid JSON?

Comment: Here`s my initial file. I changed its name and extention to "j.json" (not sure if it caused a problem).
https://www.dropbox.com/s/atfq1gtptrt4ojf/jsonResponse.rtf?dl=0

Comment: pass an `NSError` instance to the `error` parameter, then you probably get an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Good news first**

1. Your code is correct
2. Would you get either a wrong `jsonFilePath`, `contentsOfFile` would fail

**Bad news**

1. Malformed json? It seems not. Your sample parses properly
2. I have successfully created an app using your code + your json and it parses properly. I did not get an error.

**Where to go from here?**

1. Defensively use `let json = JSON(data: jsonData, options: .AllowFragments, error: &error)` and check the error. It is always good practice.
2. Which version of the SwiftyJSON are you using?

   > Installing SwiftyJSON (2.2.0)