# Swift - NSJsonSerialization - "Unable to convert data to string around character" error

Tags: ios, json, swift

I got below error when try to post an url with a dictionary as param;

> NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Unable to convert data to string around
>   character 34

And my code below;

```
    func postOrder() {

    let params = [
        “date”: ”25.12.2015”,
        “time” : “22:34”,
        “order_no”: “23232322”,
        "user_id" : “23232”
           ] as Dictionary<String, String>

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://webservis.xxxxx.com/post_order.asp")!)

    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

    request.HTTPBody = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: [])

    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in

       guard data != nil else {
            print("no data found: \(error)")
            return
        }

        let cfEnc = CFStringEncodings.ISOLatin5
        let enc = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(CFStringEncoding(cfEnc.rawValue))

        let outputString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: enc)


        do {
            if let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary {
                let success = json["success"] as? Int                                  
                print("Success: \(success)")
            } else {

                let cfEnc = CFStringEncodings.ISOLatin5
                let enc = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(CFStringEncoding(cfEnc.rawValue))

                let jsonStr = NSString(data: data!, encoding: enc)   
                print("Error could not parse JSON: \(jsonStr)")
            }
        } catch let parseError {
            print(parseError)                                                        

            let cfEnc = CFStringEncodings.ISOLatin5
            let enc = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(CFStringEncoding(cfEnc.rawValue))

            let jsonStr = NSString(data: data!, encoding: enc)
            print("Error could not parse JSON: '\(jsonStr)'")
        }
    }

    task.resume()

}
```

What is the problem on above code, can anybody help?

Comment: You are using fancy quotes... `“`, instead try using normal ones `"`.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the data you're parsing is actually valid JSON (and not just 'nearly' JSON). That error is known to occur when you have a different data format that can't be parsed as JSON.

Replace your `params` with the following and try again.

```
let params = [
        "date": "25.12.2015",
        "time" : "22:34",
        "order_no": "23232322",
        "user_id" : "23232"
           ] as Dictionary<String, String>
```

Furthermore, you may check the following thread [iOS 5 JSON Parsing Results in Cocoa Error 3840](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11174130/ios-5-json-parsing-results-in-cocoa-error-3840)